# How to completely delete a remote git tag?

Tags: git

I deleted the tags in my local and remote by running the code below.

```
#!/bin/bash

tag_list=(`git tag -l`)

for tag in ${tag_list[@]};
    do
        echo "Delete tag: $tag"
        git tag -d $tag
        git push origin :refs/tags/$tag
    done
```

If a git tag is remotely deleted, but someone else merges it into the branch, the tag is revived.
How can I completely delete a remote git tag?

Comment: is the remote a private or a public repo ? who can push to that remote: your colleagues only ? or any contributor from the internet ?

Comment: @LeGEC It is a private repository, and only co-workers can push it.

Comment: you found the solution: tell everyone to delete the tag on their machine

Answer (score 1):

You literally can't delete a remote tag at all.  When you use `git push --delete origin tag` or `git push origin :refs/tags/tag`, you're not deleting a remote tag.  You're asking a remote (another Git) to please delete *its* tag.  It may or may not obey this request, depending on what permissions some provider has added (Git itself doesn't have this kind of permissions checking but does allow hosting providers to add it on, and most do).

Assuming the remote obeys *your* request, your problem now is reduced to figuring how to make that same remote Git *stop* obeying requests from *others* to *create* that tag.  Again, you literally can't delete anyone else's tag, but if your hosting provider allows you to establish "who can create a tag" rules, you can have the hosting provider forbid others from creating that tag again.  You'll have to *ask* them to delete *their* tags too, if you want them to do that.

Once you stop thinking about this in terms of *making* someone else do something, and in terms of *asking* them (politely, or perhaps less politely with `git push --force`) and whether or not you have enforcement mechanisms for obey/don't-obey rules *on* the remote, the problem gets a lot clearer.

Comment: Deleting other workers' local git tags solved the problem. Thank you for answer.